# UITableView scroll to not-existsing cell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

My tableview contains 20 cells. The screen is placed only 8 cells, so this function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

calls 8 times and I fill only first 8 cells.

This method calls 8 times too:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if (indexPath.row == 11)
            {
                tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

and I haven't **indexPath.row == 11**.
How can I scroll to 11th cell?

Comment: Did you use swift 3.0 ?

Comment: show me your whole code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index path `let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 11, inSection: 0)`

then pass this indexPath as `self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)`

This will automatically scroll it to required cell as mentioned in indexPath.